# How do I replace column values in an R data frame with new values without doing this...?

Tags: r, function, indexing

I have a data frame with a column labeled "occasion" which ranges from 1 to 21. I would like to subset on any sequence within that range (say: 5 to 19), but then re-sequence the occasion from 5 to 19 to 1 to 15. I know how to subset. It's part 2 I'm stuck on. The only way I know how to do this is:

df$occasion[df$occasion == 5] <- 1
df$occasion[df$occasion == 6] <- 2
.
.
df$occasion[df$occasion == 19] <- 15

Is there a function or index method I can use to simplify this procedure by passing the interval (i.e., 5, 19)?  Thanks in advance. NARP (Not an R programmer)

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to start with 1, then the following could be an option:

```
df$occasion <- df$occasion-(min(df$occasion)-1)
```